# Sort QTableWidget by column the user clicked

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt6, pyqt6

I have a table widget and I want to make it so that when a user clicks on a header at the top, it sorts the table's data by the header's corresponding column in ascending order. If they click it again, it sort it by descending order. If they click another header, it get sorted by the new header's column, and if they click that again, it sorts it in opposite order yet again. Some of the columns will be text-only, so those should be sorted alphabetically in the same way.

I tried finding a signal for a table's horizontal header that is emitted when a specific element in the header is clicked, since the task would be trivial if that existed. However, no such signal exists.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.